# Filter condition using "parent" CurrentMember

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

Here is the data-set:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies(id INT, name VARCHAR(50), genre VARCHAR(50), budget DECIMAL(10));
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES
    (1, 'Pirates of the Caribbean', 'Fantasy', 379000000),
    (2, 'Avengers', 'Superhero', 365000000),
    (3, 'Star Wars', 'Science fiction', 275000000),
    (4, 'John Carter', 'Science fiction', 264000000),
    (5, 'Spider-Man', 'Superhero', 258000000),
    (6, 'Harry Potter', 'Fantasy', 250000000),
    (7, 'Avatar', 'Science fiction', 237000000);
```

To filter relatively to a constant value no problem, e.g. to get all the movies with a budget higher than 300M$:

```
WITH
    MEMBER X AS SetToStr(Filter(Movie.[Name].[Name].Members - Movie.[Name].CurrentMember, Measures.Budget > 300000000))
SELECT
    Movie.[Name].[Name].Members ON ROWS,
    X ON COLUMNS
FROM
    Cinema
```

Which gives:

```
Avatar          {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers],[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
Avengers        {[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
Harry Potter    {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers],[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
John Carter     {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers],[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
Pirates of the Caribbean    {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers]}
Spider-Man      {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers],[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
Star Wars       {[Movie].[Name].&[Avengers],[Movie].[Name].&[Pirates of the Caribbean]}
```

But how to compare to the budget of the current movie instead of the hard-coded 300M$ to get the movies more expensive than the current one?

It would give `{}` for "Pirates of the Caribbean" as it is the most expensive movie.
For "Avengers" it would be `{ 'Pirates of the Caribbean' }` as this is the second most expensive and only "Pirates of the Caribbean" is more expensive.
For "Avatar" it would give all the other movies as it is the less expensive.

The issue is that inside the `Filter` function's condition `CurrentMember` refers to the currently tested tuple and not the one currently selected on the `ROWS` axis.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Filter() for each movie, I would first compute an ordered set of movies based on budget values. Then X could be defined using the [SubSet](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Subset.php) and [Rank](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Rank.php) function.

Here is an example using a different schema but I guess you'll get the point easily:

```
with 
   set ordered_continents as order( [Geography].[Geography].[Continent], -[Measures].[#Sales] )
   member xx as SetToStr( SubSet( ordered_continents, 0, Rank( [Geography].[Geography].currentMember, ordered_continents) - 1))
   
select {[#Sales], [xx] } on 0, [Geography].[Geography].[Continent] on 1 from [Sales]
```

[image]

I'm not familiar with SSAS so I'm using icCube but I guess the MDX should be very much similar.